# Django serializers: how to deny extra fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am writing tests for my Django apps. I am using Django serializers to test API response. I found out that it allows extra fields:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()

ProjectSerializer({'name': "Project A", "state": "active"}).is_valid()
# True
ProjectSerializer().to_internal_value(data={'name': "Project A", "state": "active"})
# OrderedDict([('name', 'Project A')])
```

What I want is to ensure there will be no other fields in a response. Let's say, I expect this:

```py
data = {'name': "Project A", "state": "active"}
ProjectSerializer(data, extra='forbid').is_valid()
# False
```

---

Using [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#handling-unknown-fields) I can do it like that:

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, INCLUDE


class UserSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        unknown = RAISE
```

> RAISE (default): raise a ValidationError if there are any unknown
> fields

With [pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/model_config/#options) it will be like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, ValidationError, Extra

class Model(BaseModel, extra=Extra.forbid):
    a: str
```

> 'forbid' will cause validation to fail if extra attributes are
> included

---

Is there any options I can use with Django to perform this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need to do it this way, nor does rest-framework behave the way you are describing.
to confirm you can check the `validated_data` param that is passed down to the `create` or `update` method of the serializer.
Only the explicitly declared fields are available in the validated_data attribute (which is used for further crud operations)

Comment: And still I don't see why I can't use such a function in tests. How am I to check that API responded only with described fields?